# angular 6 PWA automate the file input click

Tags: camera, angular6, progressive-web-apps

i am using

```
<input *ngIf="selectedFile == ''" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
```

this renders a choose file control. which hitting opens the camera and picks the file. I am trying to completely avoid this manual choose file.

what would be the way to do it?

currently i have a mechanism to pass url parameter like ?action=scan . Using activatedRouter i am reading this param and render the above input control. I just want to launch camera rather.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to launch the camera directly, you have to use device element/user media with user permission and you can't use input element for the same. Check on [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images/) documentation and [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) one. Both have sample codes.

**Update:** [Here](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/capturing-camera-using-angular-5-2e177c68201f) is an Angular example.

Comment: these are raw js examples. anythng which is towards angular would be more useful

Comment: Added a link for angular.